# NSPredicate to limit latitude longitude range according to MapView bounds

Tags: swift, core-data

So I have an app with a MapView and I use CoreData to load annotations associated with locations nearby the center of the map. Currently, I define the lat/long range statically like this:

```
var fetchDataPredicates = [NSPredicate]()
fetchDataPredicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "itemLatitude BETWEEN {%f,%f} AND itemLongitude BETWEEN {%f,%f}", (latitude-0.10), (latitude+0.10), (longitude-0.10), (longitude+0.10)))
```

However, this is a pretty poor solution. If the user has zoomed out far in the map then the data would only cover a small portion of it.

Does anyone have any good ideas on how to dynamically adjust the lat/long range according to the MapView bounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely solution would be to ask the map view for its `region`. That's an `MKCoordinateRegion` which includes

- `CLLocationCoordinate2D center`
- `MKCoordinateSpan span`

The span includes longitude and latitude deltas, which look like exactly what you need.

Comment: MKCoordinateSpan looks promising. Could you give me a quick example on how the lat/long deltas can be used though?